# Create a device with arm image on Android Studio

Tags: linux, android-studio

I want to create a virtual device on Android Studio based on an ARM system image. I'm working on Debian 8 and when I lanunch the Android Virtual Device Manager all the recommended devices I watch are based on HAXM and my computer doesn't support it.

When I create a new device all devices are based on HAXM and although I have the ARM images for API 24 and 22 downloaded I can't watch any device based on it.

How can I create a device based on ARM system image?

Thanks.

Comment: You could give [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405740/android-studio-how-can-i-make-an-avd-with-arm-instead-of-haxm) a try.

Comment: I tried it with no success. In the step 4 I don't watch "Armeabi-v7a" or something like that. I try it with all the devices recommended. It's very strange.

Comment: Did you read the comment that said there should be an "Other Images" option available?

Comment: Yes. I downloaded armeabi-v7a system images for api level 24 (Android Nougat) and for api level 22 (android lollipop). When I create a new Android Virtual Device and select armeabi-v7 system image for api level 24 I watch the message repair device.